# There's some sort of error with django MPTT implementation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt

I'm a newbie to django world. While doing and academic project i'm required to implement tree structure in django.

The concept is to make a user hierarchy so that one use can come as subordinate of another user.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import mptt

from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey



class App_model(models.Model):
    case_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    p_stn= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    case_description= models.TextField()
    officer= models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)


class Testmptt(MPTTModel):
    name = models.ForeignKey(App_model)
    parent =TreeForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True,related_name='children',db_index=True)

mptt.register(Testmptt)
```

My settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'mptt',
    'django_mptt_admin',
```

My admin.py

```
from officerapp.models import App_model

from django_mptt_admin.admin import DjangoMpttAdmin

class App_modelAdmin(DjangoMpttAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(App_model,App_modelAdmin)
```

Problem is that when i use admin interface it shows error while loading form the server.

Screenshot of this error is here in the following link.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=89B428B7D40DE3FF!193&authkey=!AOg-TdOHiPfvfuA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Any one to help ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using the MPTTAdmin class on your non-MPTT model - so the admin page is looking for a bunch of fields that App_model doesn't have.  You need to use the MPTTAdmin on your Testmptt model instead.